# Best way to get started as a young engineer student trying to get into the financial world

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, books, sweden

to start of with I want to explain my situation. I'm a young student in my early twenties in my last year to finish my bachelor in engineering. I have literally searched for months now on Google and on forums (especially this forum) on the best ways to get introduced to the financial world. I have learned a lot and got a whole good advice (and bad advice) in this subject, still it's kinda hard to know what is good and what is bad since I don't have any experience in the field.

My question is as many others on this forum, how can I get started and not end up in the wrong/slow direction?  [This thread](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/best-way-to-start-investing-for-a-young-person-just-starting-their-career) specifies it good, but still the book that has the top comments is in the end about investing and putting money into Roth IRA's and long investing plans. I have no problem with these, it's just that I live in Sweden (and that's the reason for my English) and I don't know if these investing and saving methods work the same here. I can't find the correspondent to a Roth IRA here, we have something else I think.

**What tax-advantaged retirement savings options might be available for me in Sweden?**

**Is there any book, website, blog that would be the best start for me to get knowledge and then later on develop investing strategies?**

Some feedback that I have received for going through all websites/comments is that a lot of people suggest the book "[The Intelligent Investor](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://www.amazon.com/Intelligent-Investor-Definitive-Investing-Practical/dp/0060555661&ei=DKxVU6SjB4LQtAa_g4CQDg&usg=AFQjCNFyPS8kwHVJJ2bkWugnR0v-qVFCHw&sig2=5ugUXqbX5Lr6Q5cdhmbpMw&bvm=bv.65058239,d.Yms)" by Benjamin Graham. I bought this book and got through 50 pages till I got enough because I didn't know the terms, and they said this was the best first book to start with!

Some more about my background is that I have probably 1000$ to invest at the moment (It's not much, I know) and I will surely do an internship this summer before my master studies begin. I have a lot of free time to learn, that's why I need and want this.

All comments and feedback on good literature and websites will be much appreciated! Again, I know there are a lot threads about this matter, but can't get a specific answer from it regarding my case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most of the ground has been covered before. I suggest you be more specific with the issues you encountered in your research so far. For instance, one question could be to ask what tax-advantaged retirement savings options might be available to you in Sweden.

Comment: Ok, sure. I'll edit it too that specific question. THank you.

Comment: Suggest you trim away the rest. The question remains, in large part, broad and duplicating the other. Small, focused questions are better that a bunch at one time.

Comment: Hmm, don't know what you mean. Do you mean I should shorten it? Can you help me with that and suggest an edit? I still need an answer to the question regarding literature, since its not the same as the question in the other post. Thank you

Comment: Two separate, new questions. Keep each simple. Three sentences top. Go.