# Start Investing - France

Tags: starting-out-investing, france

I live in France and I am 20. I am in my 3rd year of computer science degree. Not working regularly yet !

I would like to start investing my savings into something profitale.

I currently have a LDD, a Livret Jeune and CEL. 
Should I go to my bank to ask questions about investement ?

The problem is that I don't know where to start and I am not interested in watching stock exchange rates all day long. 
I just want to place it somewhere and let it grow ^^

Could you give me advices or just tell me how you started your investing plan ?

Thank you !

Comment: You aren't working yet and don't have a background in finance, so don't try dabbing into the markets as of yet(stocks or bonds). I see that LDD pays you an interest of 1%, I know it isn't much but play safe for the time being. `I am not interested in watching stock exchange rates all day long` That isn't helpful either if you aren't a trader in a bank or something. Read some books on investing to start with. Read an introductory book on understanding financial statements. That should prepare you when you start working.

Comment: I'll start working in 2 years (best case scenario), maybe 3.
Maybe you have some book recommandations ?

Comment: Have a look here http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/best-way-to-start-investing-for-a-young-person-just-starting-their-career. Some body like you only, but the person is in US but still you will get some idea.

Comment: Well that's not really helpful for your question but why have you opened a CEL since the PEL is more lucrative ? Since you speak about letting the money "sleeping" there, there is no inconvenient of having locked up money for 4 years (that can be extended to 10)... The advice that all french should keep is to fill their Livret Jeune (1600.00€) as soon as possible to that you get the maximum of interests ! (banks won't help you, their job is to take your money, not to help you taking their ^^)

Comment: My Livret Jeune is filled. At the time when I opended my CEL I was 16 and I earned money only during the holidays.
With a PEL, you need to put at least 45 euros a month.
But I just called my banker and I am opening my PEL in 2 weeks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not interested in watching stock exchange rates all day long. I just want to place it somewhere and let it grow

Your intuition is spot on! To **buy & hold** is the sensible thing to do.  There is no need to constantly monitor the stock market. To invest successfully you only need some **basic pointers**. People make it look like it's more complicated than it actually is for individual investors. You might find useful some wisdom pearls I wish I had learned even earlier.

1. **Stocks & Bonds**

**Stocks & Bonds are the best passive investment available**. Stocks offer the best return, while bonds are reduce risk. The stock/bond allocation depends of your risk tolerance. Since you're as young as it gets, I would forget about bonds until later and go with a full stock portfolio. Banks are glorified money mausoleums; the interest you can get from them is rarely noticeable.

2. **Index investing**

**Index investing is the best alternative**. How so? Because **'you can't beat the market'**. Nobody can; but people like to try and fail. 
So instead of trying, some fund managers simply **track a market index** (always successfully) while others try to beat it (consistently failing). Actively managed mutual funds have higher costs for the extra work involved. **Avoid them like the plague.**

Look for a **diversified** index fund with **low TER** (Total Expense Ratio). These are the most important factors. Diversification will increase safety, while low costs guarantee that you get the most out of your money. **Vanguard** has truly good index funds, as well as **Blackrock** (**iShares**).

3. **Broker**

Since you can't simply buy equity by yourself, you need a broker to buy and sell. Luckily, there are many **good online brokers in Europe**. What we're looking for in a broker is **safety** (run background checks, ask other 
[wise individual investors that have taken time out of their schedules to read the small print](https://econowiser.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/new-index-investing-strategy-meesman-binck-and-maybe-interactive-brokers/)) and that charges us with **low fees**. You probably can do this through the bank, but... well, it defeats its own purpose.

4. **Tax advantages**

US citizens have their [401(k) accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/401%28k%29). Very neat stuff. Check your country's law to see if you can make use of something similar to reduce the tax cost of investing. Your government will want a slice of those juicy dividends. An alternative is to buy an index fund on which dividends are not distributed, but are [automatically reinvested](https://www.ishares.com/lu/individual/en/products/251882/ishares-msci-world-ucits-etf-acc-fund) instead.

Some links for further reference:

[Investment 101, and why index investment rocks](http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2011/05/18/how-to-make-money-in-the-stock-market/): However the author is based in the US, so you might find the next link useful.

[Investment for Europeans](https://econowiser.wordpress.com/index-investing-for-europeans/): Very useful to check specific information regarding European investing.

[Portfolio Ideas](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Lazy_portfolios): You'll realise you don't actually need many equities, since the diversification is built-in the index funds.

I hope this helps! There's not much more, but it's all condensed in a handful of blogs.

Answer (score 2):

In france you have several options:

## Livrets

### Livret A & LDD:

A good place to starts with: *1%* as of may 2015 interest is low, but's money is 100% liquid (you can withdraw antime).

### PEL (Plan épargne logement):

You got slightly superior interest rates, and have to wire at least 45€ a month on it. It gives you lots of advantages if you use it to buy a house.
You cannot use the money unless you close the account, so it's not as flexible.
You get *2%* rates as of may 2015 which is quite good.
[If you open this account now, it's only 1% making it not so attractive. Look at Life Insurance Instead.]

### CEL

This one is useless: interest rate is too low.

## Others

### Life insurance (Assurance Vie)

I highly recommend this one.
You can open it with 0 cost with several online banks (ing, boursorama, ...)
Minimum deposit should be around 1000€.
Rate is flexible, but usually higher than what you get with the others.
You shouldn't withdraw the money before *8 years* (because of taxes, but you can still do it if you need).
You can add money on it later if you want.
Because of the 8 year duration, it's better to open one as soon as you can, even with the minimum amount.

### Summary

Open an PEL + Livret A + Life insurance.

Put the minimum on both PEL + life insurance.
Put every thing else on Livret A.
If you are 100% sure you don't need some of the livret A money, send it to PEL.
[As of 2017, PEL is not so attractive anymore. Bet on the Life Insurance instead, unless your account was open prior to this].

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have an LDD. If your income is below a certain threshold (as of today, 19 255 € a year for a single person; quite likely if you're just a student), then you can open a [**Livret d'épargne populaire**](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2367) (in short, LEP).

It works almost exactly the same as a Livret A / LDD, except that:

- your income must be below the threshold already mentioned: 19 255 € a year for a single person;
- the interest rate is higher: 1,25 % instead of 0,75 %;
- the deposit limit is lower: 7 700 € instead of 22 950 € (Livret A) or 12 000 € (LDD).

Just like a Livret A / LDD:

- you can only own one;
- you can freely deposit or withdraw money from it;
- there is no tax on the income generated.

You should fill it up first before putting money in your LDD (assuming your Livret Jeune is maxed out, they have typically a higher rate than the LEP). If your bank is anything like mine, the very existence of the LEP is not very well-advertised, and I found that not many people are even aware that they exist.

---

PS: The [French administration's website has a whole section dedicated to financial matters](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/N19803). It's usually very clear and detailed. I advise you to check it out.